# Magento 2 : How to get top 10 repeated values in a column using CRUD instead of sql?

Tags: magento2, collection, model, sql, crud

I want to get top 10 most repeated values in a column of my table, I can do so using sql but I need to do it using CRUD i.e using collections or model as magento coding standard doesn't allow naked sql queries (MEQP1.SQL.RawQuery.FoundRawSql) - [documentation](http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/extensions/review-code-validation.html)

How would I go about doing so? Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Following is the sql query which can be used to do just what is required ..

```
SELECT `tag`, COUNT(`tag`) AS `value_occurrence` FROM `Faq_Tags` GROUP BY `tag` ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC LIMIT 10
```

I know how to order by, group by and set limit using magento collection but **I am still not able to figure out how to get count('tag') using collection**. Please help me regarding this.